# C# OR Javascript Permutations of two arrays multiple times

Tags: c#, arrays, permutation, concatenation

I've been working, giving up and then reworking on this problem for a couple days. I've looked at a lot of different ways to go about however I either can't implement it correctly or it doesn't suit what I need it to do.

Basically: I have two arrays, prefix and suffix

```
 prefix = { 0, 0, 3, 8, 8, 15} 
 suffix = { 0, 3, 2, 7, 7, 9, 12, 15 }
```

I need to:

- Have a minimum of 3 used combined (2+1 or 1+2) and a max of 6 used (3+3).
- Not use an affix more than once (except when it's repeated (ie there's two 8's in prefix))

The end goal is to see what combinations can equal X.

eg

```
X = 42
3 + 8 + 8 + 2 + 9 + 12 = 42
0 + 8 + 8 + 7 + 7 + 12 = 42
| Prefix |  | Suffix |

15 + 12 + 15 = 42
0 + 15 + 0 + 12 + 15 = 42
```

I've tried looking into Permutations, IEnumerables, Concat's etc. but cannot find something that'll do this successfully.

These are the 'full' arrays I'm needing to work with.

```
public int[] Prefix = {0, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 16, 15, 15, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 23 };
public int[] Suffix = {0, 3, 3, 9, 11, 11, 11, 17, 18, 18, 20, 25, 25, 27, 30, 30};
```

Any help is appreciated, if I'm unclear about anything I'll clarify as best as possible, Thanks!

Edit: I was also suggested to run it to equate all possible outcomes and store it in a hash table to be used when the correct values are used? Not sure which would work best.

Comment: There is no built-in solution for the task, you'll have to come up with an algorithm on your own.

Comment: Personally, I would recommend make a bruteforce colliding with X.

Comment: Are you allowed to use 4+2 or 5+1 affixes?

Comment: @Douglas I believe it is maximum of 3 and minimum of 1 for each affix and also minimum of 3 for total count.

Comment: Do you plan on excluding duplicates? For example, in your samples `Prefix` has six entries of `8`, seven entries for `12`, and `Suffix` has three entries of `11`. If you you're solving for a sum of `31`, I think that will yield 126 duplicate results based on those entries alone.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair In case of `IEnumerable<>` solution (and it should be that way I believe) he can always add the `.Distinct()` thing.

Comment: @Chris Sinclair I'm only using that array as an example, each number has a separate string value associated with it so even though there is multiples of the one number, they're unique according to their string value association.

Comment: @Douglas What AgentFire said, 3 + 3 is the max aloud for each.

Comment: Just solved your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the "OR Javascript" option...

1. Make an associative array mapping totals of the prefixes to an array of the permutations of prefixes which generate that total; then populate it.
2. Make a second associative array similar for the suffixes but only populate it with suffix permutations if `expected_result - total` is in the associative array for prefixes.
3. Output the valid suffixes and corresponding prefixes.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4sKmL/2/)

```
// Inputs
var prefixes = [0, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 16, 15, 15, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 23],
    suffixes = [0, 3, 3, 9, 11, 11, 11, 17, 18, 18, 20, 25, 25, 27, 30, 30],
    expected_result = 42;

// Associative Arrays
var prefixTotals = {},
    suffixTotals = {},
// Functions
    addTotal     = function( map, arr, other_map ){
        var t = 0, i = 0;
        for ( ; i < arr.length; ++i )
            t += arr[i].value;
        if (   ( other_map === undefined )
            || ( ( expected_result - t ) in other_map ) )
        {
            if ( !( t in map ) )
                map[t] = [];
            map[t].push( arr );
        }
    },
    calcPermutations     = function( affixes, map, other_map ) {
        var i = 0, j, k, l = affixes.length;
        for ( ; i < l; ++i )
        {
            addTotal( map, [ { index: i, value: affixes[i] } ], other_map );
            for ( j = i+1; j < l; ++j )
            {
                addTotal( map, [ { index: i, value: affixes[i] }, { index: j, value: affixes[j] } ], other_map );
                for ( k = j+1; k < l; ++k )
                {
                    addTotal( map, [ { index: i, value: affixes[i] }, { index: j, value: affixes[j] }, { index: k, value: affixes[k] } ], other_map );
                }
            }
        }
    },
    resultToString = function( affixes ){
        var s = [];
        for ( var i = 0; i < affixes.length; ++i )
            s.push( affixes[i].index + '=>' + affixes[i].value );
        return s.join(',');
    };

calcPermutations( prefixes, prefixTotals, undefined );
calcPermutations( suffixes, suffixTotals, prefixTotals );

var i,j,k,p,s,count = 0,html=[];
for ( i in suffixTotals )
{
    s = suffixTotals[i];
    p = prefixTotals[expected_result - i];
    for ( j = 0; j < p.length; ++j )
        for ( k = 0; k < s.length; ++k )
            html.push( 'Prefixes [' + resultToString( p[j] ) + '], Suffixes [' + resultToString( s[k] ) + ']' );
    count += p.length * s.length;
}
html.unshift( 'There were ' + count + ' valid permutations:' );

document.getElementById( 'out' ).innerHTML = html.join( '<br />' );
```

Comment: Thank you for this- I'll have a proper view after some sleep but looks useful.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested you can of course nest loops till Pascal complains about his triangle, but you could also take a completely probabilistic approach if you wish :)

After all, when the brute-force solution is executing, [a rogue alpha particle can flip an entire bit in the memory cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109218/do-gamma-rays-from-the-sun-really-flip-bits-every-once-in-a-while) and it won't come up with the right answer anyway. (This is a joke. Don't downvote me please, let the cosmic rays hitting the SO server take care of that.)

```
42 ==  
  prefix.OrderBy(x => random.Next(0,prefix.Length)).Take(random.Next(1,4)).Sum() 
  + 
  suffix.OrderBy(x => random.Next(0,suffix.Length)).Take(random.Next(1,4)).Sum();
```

Here's a demo,

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace WhatWasTheQuestion {
    class Program {
        static readonly int[] prefix = { 0, 0, 3, 8, 8, 15 };
        static readonly int[] suffix = { 0, 3, 2, 7, 7, 9, 12, 15 };
        static readonly Random random = new Random();

        static bool generateAndCheckCandidate(int X) {
            var prefixCandidates = prefix.OrderBy(x => random.Next(0, prefix.Length)).Take(random.Next(1, 4)).ToList();
            var suffixCandidates = suffix.OrderBy(x => random.Next(0, suffix.Length)).Take(random.Next(1, 4)).ToList();
            if (prefixCandidates.Sum() + suffixCandidates.Sum() == X) {
                Console.WriteLine(X + " = "  + String.Join("+", prefixCandidates) + "+" + String.Join("+", suffixCandidates));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int maxAttempts = 10000;
            while (maxAttempts > 0 && !generateAndCheckCandidate(42))
            {
                --maxAttempts;
            }
        }
    }
}
// Output:
// 42 = 8+15+0+0+7+12+0
```

Comment: This works, however meeting the [2 + 1/ 1 + 2] to [ 3 + 3 ] as trying to equal 24 with this array doesn't work out pre = {0, 6, 6, 8} and suf = {0, 3, 3, 9} where {6 + 6}+{3 + 9} would be an acceptable result.

Comment: Ah but I said this is probabilistic :) Just weed out the combinations of unsuitable length. For example you can check the suffixCandidates.Length and prefixCandidates.Length before you sum, or you could generate a length for one of them and that would constrain the random length for the other.

Answer (score 1):

This is an intuitive (albeit slow) solution using LINQ:

```
int[] prefixes = { 0, 0, 3, 8, 8, 15 };
int[] suffixes = { 0, 3, 2, 7, 7, 9, 12, 15 };
int target = 42;

var results =
    from prefixLength in Enumerable.Range(1, 3)
    from suffixLength in Enumerable.Range(1, 3)
    where prefixLength + suffixLength >= 3
    from prefixPermutation in prefixes.GetPermutations(prefixLength)
    from suffixPermutation in suffixes.GetPermutations(suffixLength)
    let affixPermutation = prefixPermutation.Concat(suffixPermutation)
    where affixPermutation.Sum() == target
    select string.Join(" + ", affixPermutation);

var final = results.Distinct().ToArray();
```

I've used a few rudimentary enumerable extensions:

```
public static partial class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPermutations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int length)
    {
        if (length == 0)
        {
            yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
            yield break;
        }

        int index = 0;
        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            IEnumerable<T> remainder = source.ExceptAt(index);
            IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> tails = GetPermutations(remainder, length - 1);
            foreach (IEnumerable<T> tail in tails)
                yield return tail.Prepend(item);
            index++;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> ExceptAt<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int index)
    {
        return source.Take(index).Concat(source.Skip(index + 1));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T first)
    {
        yield return first;
        foreach (T item in source)
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's an efficient solution when determining permutations--thankfully the OP wasn't looking for combinations!

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: Algorithmically speaking, I agree. I meant that I assume the implementation could be improved using techniques such as memoization.

Comment: I see what you mean now!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for that big amount of code. It is not indian though and complete 100% working:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Sum: ");

            var sum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            var prefix = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
            var suffix = new[] { 0, 3, 2, 7, 7, 9, 12, 15 };

            foreach (var item in Solution(prefix, suffix, 1, 3, sum))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} = [ {1} ] + [ {2} ]", sum, string.Join(" + ", item.Item1.Select(T => prefix[T])), string.Join(" + ", item.Item2.Select(T => suffix[T])));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done here. Any key to close.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int[], int[]>> Solution(int[] one, int[] two, int minElementCount, int maxElementCount, int sum)
        {
            if (one.Length < minElementCount || two.Length < minElementCount)
            {
                throw new Exception("Nah.");
            }

            var cacheOne = new Dictionary<int, List<int[]>>();
            var cacheTwo = new Dictionary<int, List<int[]>>();
            var result = new List<Tuple<int[], int[]>>();

            for (int countInOne = minElementCount; countInOne <= Math.Min(one.Length, maxElementCount); countInOne++)
            {
                for (int countInTwo = minElementCount; countInTwo <= Math.Min(two.Length, maxElementCount); countInTwo++)
                {
                    List<int[]> permutationsOne;
                    List<int[]> permutationsTwo;

                    if (!cacheOne.TryGetValue(countInOne, out permutationsOne))
                    {
                        permutationsOne = cacheOne[countInOne] = PermutationsIndices(one, countInOne).ToList();
                    }

                    if (!cacheTwo.TryGetValue(countInTwo, out permutationsTwo))
                    {
                        permutationsTwo = cacheTwo[countInTwo] = PermutationsIndices(two, countInTwo).ToList();
                    }

                    foreach (var permutationOne in permutationsOne)
                    {
                        var sumOne = permutationOne.Select(T => one[T]).Sum();

                        if (sumOne <= sum)
                        {
                            foreach (var permutationTwo in permutationsTwo)
                            {
                                if ((sumOne + permutationTwo.Select(T => two[T]).Sum() == sum))
                                {
                                    yield return Tuple.Create(permutationOne, permutationTwo);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public static IEnumerable<int[]> PermutationsIndices<T>(this T[] e, int count)
        {
            if (count > e.Length)
            {
                throw new Exception("Nah.");
            }

            return TraverseArray(e, new Stack<int>(), 0, count - 1);
        }
        public static IEnumerable<int[]> TraverseArray<T>(T[] array, Stack<int> stack, int index, int iterations)
        {
            for (int i = index; i < array.Length - iterations; i++)
            {
                stack.Push(i);

                if (iterations == 0)
                {
                    yield return stack.Reverse().ToArray();
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (int[] item in TraverseArray(array, stack, i + 1, iterations - 1))
                    {
                        yield return item;
                    }
                }

                stack.Pop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

So, the output for your task ...

```
prefix = { 0, 0, 3, 8, 8, 15 }
suffix = { 0, 3, 2, 7, 7, 9, 12, 15 }
```

Will be this:

```
Sum: 42
42 = [ 15 ] + [ 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 8 ] + [ 7 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 8 ] + [ 7 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 8 ] + [ 7 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 8 ] + [ 7 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 15 ] + [ 0 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 15 ] + [ 3 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 15 ] + [ 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 15 ] + [ 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 3 + 15 ] + [ 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 8 + 15 ] + [ 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 8 + 15 ] + [ 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 8 + 15 ] + [ 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 8 + 15 ] + [ 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 15 ] + [ 3 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 15 ] + [ 3 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 3 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 3 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 3 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 3 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 3 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 3 + 15 ] + [ 3 + 9 + 12 ]
42 = [ 3 + 15 ] + [ 2 + 7 + 15 ]
42 = [ 3 + 15 ] + [ 2 + 7 + 15 ]
42 = [ 8 + 8 ] + [ 2 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 8 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 8 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 8 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 8 + 15 ] + [ 3 + 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 8 + 15 ] + [ 3 + 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 8 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 8 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 8 + 15 ] + [ 3 + 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 8 + 15 ] + [ 3 + 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 0 + 0 + 15 ] + [ 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 3 + 15 ] + [ 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 3 + 15 ] + [ 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 3 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 3 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 3 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 3 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 8 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 2 + 9 ]
42 = [ 0 + 0 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 0 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 0 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 0 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 0 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 12 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 0 + 15 ] + [ 3 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 3 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 3 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 3 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 3 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 3 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 3 + 15 ] + [ 3 + 9 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 3 + 15 ] + [ 2 + 7 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 3 + 15 ] + [ 2 + 7 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 8 ] + [ 2 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 3 + 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 3 + 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 3 + 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 3 + 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 0 + 3 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 3 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 3 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 3 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 3 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 3 + 15 ] + [ 3 + 9 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 3 + 15 ] + [ 2 + 7 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 3 + 15 ] + [ 2 + 7 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 8 ] + [ 2 + 9 + 15 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 3 + 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 3 + 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 7 + 12 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 3 + 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 0 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 3 + 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 3 + 8 + 8 ] + [ 2 + 9 + 12 ]
42 = [ 3 + 8 + 8 ] + [ 7 + 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 3 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 3 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 3 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 2 + 7 + 7 ]
42 = [ 3 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 3 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 7 + 9 ]
42 = [ 3 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 2 + 7 + 7 ]
42 = [ 8 + 8 + 15 ] + [ 0 + 2 + 9 ]
Done here. Any key to close.
```

Comment: Wow thanks for coming back to this! I'll be implementing this tonight.

Comment: @Ministry any progress? I'd like to see an accepted answer in this topic :p.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a pretty solution, but it is a working one.
Note how I made sure that both prefix and suffix have two zeroes at the start, so as to also include the case where you only use one or two values from that array.

```
    int[] prefix = { 0, 0, 3, 8, 8, 15};
    int[] suffix = { 0, 0, 3, 2, 7, 7, 9, 12, 15 };
    for(int p1 = 0; p1 < prefix.Length; p1++) {
        for(int p2 = 0; p2 < prefix.Length; p2++) {
            for(int p3 = 0; p3 < prefix.Length; p3++) {
                for(int s1 = 0; s1 < suffix.Length; s1++) {
                    for(int s2 = 0; s2 < suffix.Length; s2++) {
                        for(int s3 = 0; s3 < suffix.Length; s3++) {
                            if(prefix[p1] + prefix[p2] + prefix[p3] + suffix[s1] + suffix[s2] + suffix[s3] == 42)
                            {
                                System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} + {1} + {2} + {3} + {4} + {5} = 42", prefix[p1], prefix[p2], prefix[p3], suffix[s1], suffix[s2], suffix[s3] ));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `Indian-Code` rulles!

Comment: Loops endlessly/an excessive amount.

Comment: @Ministry probably not endlessly, but probably a very very long time since you have 6 nested for loops!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative which brute-forces the solution. I had to write it on .NET 3 without LINQ, so I wrote my own helper methods for summing and joining the values - hence the large amount of code. 
`EnumerateIndices` and `Sum42` are doing all the work though. You can make it a lot shorter using LINQ, but I don't have access to that now so I'll leave it for you to clean this up before I accidentally introduce any errors.

```
public static IEnumerable<int[]> EnumerateIndices(int[] values, int length)
{
    int[] result = new int[length]; 
    int size = (int)(Math.Pow(values.Length, length));
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        int tmp = i;
        for(int j = length - 1; j >= 0; --j)
        {
            result[j] = values[tmp % values.Length];
            tmp /= values.Length;               
        }

        yield return result;
    }       
}

public static int Sum(int[] values)
{
    // Just a helper method - if you can use LINQ replace by values.Sum()
    int result = 0, size = values.Length;       
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        result += values[i];
    }
    return result;
}

public static string Join(string separator, int[] values)
{
    // Just a helper method, if you can use LINQ replace by sth like string.Join(separator, values.ToArray<string>())
    string[] stringValues = new string[values.Length];  
    int size = values.Length;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        stringValues[i] = values[i].ToString(); 
    }
    return string.Join(separator, stringValues);
}

public static void Sum42()
{
    int[] prefix = { 0, 0, 3, 8, 8, 15};
    int[] suffix = { 0, 3, 2, 7, 7, 9, 12, 15 };

    IEnumerable<int[]> prefixes = EnumerateIndices(prefix, 3);
    IEnumerable<int[]> suffixes = EnumerateIndices(suffix, 3);
    foreach(int[] p in prefixes) {
        foreach(int[] s in suffixes) {
            if(Sum(p) + Sum(s) == 42)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = 42", Join(" + ", p), Join(" + ", s)); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks perfect as I'm hoping to be able to transpose it across to jQuery with as little hassle as possible. I let it run for 42 with my larger array and it was still running when I got back a few minutes latter (30k+ results to equal 42). 

Is there a way to prevent it from using the same values just in a different order? It's fine to use the separate ones differently but if it's just doing it in a different order: 0(a) + 8(a) + 8(b) + 3(a) + (3) (b) is the same as 8(a) + 0(a) + 8(b) + 3(a) + 3(b). Regards

Comment: Also I can't figure out a solution to making the EnumerateIndices be able to be 2 + 1, 1 + 2, 2 + 2, 3 + 2, 2 + 3 or 3 + 3.

Comment: Don't know about the duplication problem. The second argument to `EnumerateIndices` determines how many values it will take from the array.

Comment: @Ministry: And if you make sure that you have two zeroes in each of the arrays, it will automatically include those cases you mention, because it will also try e.g. [0 + 0 + (other prefix)] + [0 + 0 + (other suffix)], etc.

Comment: I decided to just drop the 0 values from the array, I can deal without them and it makes it a whole lot neater. EnumerateIndices(Suffix.Distinct().ToArray(), 2); Distinct stops it from reusing the same method in a different order, however I still don't know how I could get it to run through all the accepted values  from the array (2 + 1 / 1 + 2 etc) without doing a bunch of different foreach loops then combining the result