# Should I be using both lock and volatile?

Tags: java, locking, volatile

My understanding of volatile is that it ensures that the value is always read from memory, so as far as I can see, in the following example, the `myObject` variable would need to be volatile to avoid a `NullPointerException` being raised:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
private MyObject myObject = null;

//...

synchronized (lock) {
    if (myObject == null) {
        myObject = new MyObject();
    }

    myObject.blah();

    // some other stuff that I want synchronized
}
```

`myObject` is only ever touched in the synchronized block. `lock` is only every used to synchronize that block.

Is that correct?

So rephrased slightly, my question is...imagine two threads are hitting that code. First thread locks and sets myObject, calls `.blah()` and any other code within the synchronized block and exits the synchronized block. This allows thread two to enter the synchronized block. Without setting `myObject` to volatile, is there are chance it could still evaluate `myObject == null` to `true`?

Comment: Is `myObject` volatile? Also, is `Object lock` *constant* for all instances of your class?

Comment: Is there any other code that can set `myObject` to `null`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - no imagine this code is self contained.

Comment: I think there might be a chance, I've had not so happy experiences using `synchronized` blocks, where unexpected results happened and synchronization didn't work, especially at the beginning of a process. Better use `ReentrantLock`. And as for `volatile`, it has nothing to do with synchronization in this case, so not needed.

Comment: @dabadaba - I am not really asking about synchronization...more whether I can ensure that I don't get a NPE accessing `myObject`.

Comment: I think you can get the exception, `synchronized` blocks are not perfect.

Comment: If `Object lock` has the same instance for all the threads this reference will be used, then there's no need to mark `myObject` as `volatile`.

Comment: @dabadaba that would be a [cosmic ray](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2580933/1065197).

Answer (score 4):

The `synchronized`  block will ensure the updates to memory is seen by other threads. There is no need to make `myObject`  volatile.

From [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html):

> When a thread releases an intrinsic lock, a happens-before
>   relationship is established between that action and any subsequent
>   acquistion of the same lock.

Comment: I've been doing some research, as I wondered why I thought you needed the volatile keyword in there. I believe it was to do with DCL, this: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html. Now am I right in saying because I don't have the check for null on the outside of my synchronization loop, I don't need the check?

Answer (score 0):

I think volatile is not needed here, because every thread which goes into synchronized block is checking myObject references, so myObject should be instantieted when first thread goes into block, other threads are secured by checking is myObject not null. For me looks good.

EDIT: I hope there is only this one block where you want to use myObect reference, and you do not change this reference before or after synchoronize block.

Comment: But is there not a chance that the value could sit in a cache somewhere and therefore result in an NPE?

Comment: No. There is no such posibility.

Comment: In code which you paste, every thread (but only one at the time) will check myObject value, then run blah method, so every other thread will wait. But you cannot implement second block where you set myObject=null, because then will happen something like you said. If you want to set null to myObject you need to do it in one block.