# PL/SQL limitation in for-loops in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, oracle11g

i have a table that have about 30 million record and i want to loop on the records that exists in the table like this :

```
for i in (select * from tbl_items it
             Left join location lo 
              On lo.id=it.location_id) loop 
     // check some condition 
     // insert into log table 
end loop ;
```

is there any limitation in for loops inside a procedure in PL/SQL in Oracle11g ? 
i thinks it's have limitation and how can i have skip the limit ?

Comment: That's likely to be extremely slow ...

Comment: No, there is no limit (it would be pretty stupid if there was)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i think there is a limit , i try a insert and i want to insert data in another table it just insert about 1 million !!

Comment: But why do you think that's a PL/SQL loop limitiation? What error did you get? What logic is inside the loop? Is there really a good reason to use PL/SQL instead of a plain SQL `insert ... select` statement, which would usually be much faster and more efficient?

Comment: A loop is a bad choice for that. Just do a `insert into target_table (col1, col2, col3) select c1, c2, c3 from source_table` that will be a **lot** faster

Answer (score 4):

PL/SQL does not have any practical limit on the number of iterations in a loop.

I can't prove it but here are my reasons for saying there is no limit:

1. No limit is listed in the [PL/SQL Program Limits](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/limits.htm#LNPLS018) section of the Database PL/SQL Language Reference.  One thing Oracle is usually good at is keeping the hard limits to a minimum or always having a workaround.
2. Creating a limit like this in a programming language doesn't make sense.
3. One reason I started concentrating on Oracle SQL and PL/SQL many years ago was to avoid a programming language that had an iteration limit.  Few programming problems are more depressing than an error like "maximum loop limit exceeded".  If this problem existed in PL/SQL a lot of people would know and be angry about it.

At *some* point every loops dies - you'll run out of a resource.  But for a sane language like PL/SQL you can worry more about [cosmic rays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580933/cosmic-rays-what-is-the-probability-they-will-affect-a-program).

---

Perhaps by "limit" you mean the `LIMIT` bulk collect option?  If so, Oracle cursor-FOR loops use a limit of 100.  Which means it will fetch 100 rows at a time.  This is a good trade-off between memory and reducing overhead and in practice is always good enough.

---

As a_horse_with_no_name suggested, avoiding loops completely is a best practice in Oracle SQL.  Set based programs are almost always faster than row-by-row.

Comment: I have some logic inside the loop , so i must use the loop , and the select in the loop join from 3,4 table

Comment: @MohammadMirzaeyan That's fine, it should still work.  Whatever the problem is it's not caused by some PL/SQL loop limit.  Can you add some more information about exactly what's going wrong?

Comment: I edit the question , the problem is when i call the procedure with a item id it will be insert into log table but when i dont put item id where clause it wont insert it .

Comment: There's no "item id" or "log table" in your question so I still don't know what problem you are having. Please add a [simple example reproducing the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).