# Do I need to worry about corrupt memory in an otherwise correct program?

Tags: memory, embedded-linux

We're working on an application meant to run on an embedded system, in a moderately harsh environment (a controller for a heating system in a residential building).

That application should run for years without needing to reboot the system. It runs on an embedded PC running Linux. The program instantiates several classes whose lifetime is the same as the application's.

Should I worry about memory becoming corrupt over such a long lifetime? Does it make sense to periodically check the class invariants to detect any such memory corruption? Or does modern hardware make such corruption astronomically unlikely?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580933/cosmic-rays-what-is-the-probability-they-will-affect-a-program

Answer (score 0):

I have seen my share of cheap sd cards on boards, they can die on you easily.
Few months ago have been dealing with one maker, under high data throughput SD card was unable to react in time. Some irq failure messages pop up and whole partition blows up.
If it's not intended for mass production I would definitely suggest you to choose some good and recommended storage.
But really, I can not remember memory corruption issues(besides rom), I would worry about memory leaks. Those are the most nasty problems for embedded system intended to last long without reboot.
Have to be really careful, they can happen either in userspace or in kernel space. Even software which you have always had confidence in may have them, depending on the build version. Have to choose Linux distribution carefully, if there is no dedicated kernel development team usually this stuff is outsourced to companies which build stable systems, where every included package is tested and confirmed to not leak.
In the end, definitely a few cycles of stress testing are needed, if there are problems with memory you will notice.